# web2py View : Height (size) of a select box in

Tags: html, css, web2py

In web2py, I wish to render a select box with size="3"
sothat it will display 3 items (instead of default size 1)
~~~The code, if tested in a standalone html file, works correct (the size is 3)

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>ABC</h1>
<FORM name="drop_list" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td><select id="List1" name="ABC" size="3"></select></td>
<td><input type="button" id="addtype" value="Add to List"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select id="List2" name="selABC" size="3"></select></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
<script language="javascript">
function addOption(selectbox,text,value)
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = text;
optn.value = value;
selectbox.options.add(optn);
}

function addOption_list(selectbox){
var ctg = JSON.parse('{{=XML(ctg_list)}}');
for (var i=0; i < ctg.length; ++i){
addOption(document.drop_list.ABC, ctg[i], ctg[i]);
}
}
window.onload = addOption_list;
</script>

<script>
$('#addtype').click(function(){
var index=document.getElementById("List1").selectedIndex;
var elOpt = document.getElementById("List1").options[index];
var elSel = document.getElementById("List2");

var elOptNew = document.createElement("option");
elOptNew.text = elOpt.text;
elOptNew.value = elOpt.value;

try {
  elSel.add(elOptNew, null);} // standards compliant doesnt work in IE 
catch(ex) {
  elSel.add(elOptNew);} // IE only 
  }) 
</script>
```

In web2py view, its height(size) remains unaltered (1).
It displays a tiny scrollbar though.

Any tip as to why my code in web2py "View" is not able to override the default size of 1?

Thanks,
Vineet

Comment: It works OK for me in the current 'welcome' app. Can you show some code?

Comment: @Anthony, I have edited my original post to include the code in "View" file. Secondly, I also tried to render this select box in welcome app. But the result is same (size="1" is unaltered) Maybe, you can indicate a possible bug in this code; or any other workaround.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot replicate your problem. I pasted your exact code above into the index.html view file of the standard web2py 'welcome' app in version 1.98.2, and I get two select boxes that are both 3 lines in height. What browser and OS are you using? Have you tried other browsers? Maybe you can send a full application replicating the problem to the web2py mailing list.